# Updating Azure AD Application via C#

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-sdk-.net

I have an already existing Azure AD Application. I would like to be able to update it via C# code, just like I do via the Azure CLI. All I need is to add two new reply URLs to the application.

With the Azure CLI I use:

```
az ad app update --id <my_app_id> --reply-urls <url_1> <url_2>
```

How can I get the equivalent but within C# code? I've found that the Azure SDK does not provide such a functionality, or at least I couldn't find it.
I have a Service Principal which I want this operation done through.

Comment: You can do this using the [Microsoft Graph .NET Client Library](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet).

Comment: I will look into it, thank you

Comment: I found the graph api which can solve your issue, and if you need to use asp.net core SDK here?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one solution I came up with, turns out you can use `System.Diagnostics.Process` to invoke CMD.exe via C# and use the cli through there:

```
string strCmdText;
            strCmdText = "/C az login --service-principal -u <client_id> -p <client_secret> --tenant <tenant_id>";
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", strCmdText);
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", "/C az ad app update --id <app_id> --reply-urls https://testfromcsharp.com/");
```

and it worked.

EDIT: The best solution was to use the Microsoft Graph SDK within my .NET project and authenticate/invoke functions through it. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/sdks-overview

Answer (score 1):

You can use this [graph api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example) to update your azure ad appliction. And pls note that the `application id` used in the request url is the object id of the azure ad
application but not the application id.

[image]

You can first call `Get https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/object_id_here` first to get the current `web` claim of this app, that should be similar to

```
{
    "web": {
        "homePageUrl": null,
        "logoutUrl": null,
        "redirectUris": [
            "http://localhost:3000"
        ],
        "implicitGrantSettings": {
            "enableAccessTokenIssuance": true,
            "enableIdTokenIssuance": true
        }
    }
}
```

Then you modify the `redirectUris` property with all the urls you wanna set to the application, pls note this update will cover all the original redirect urls. Then copy the json content and call the `PATCH` request to update the api.

[image]